# How can I kill Thread by another thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4, kill

I created a program that it has two class, BookPage class shows window( make with PYQT4)  and another class (RfidThreadClass) do busy waiting loop.

Now i want stop created thread in Bookpage class with stop() method, but it doesn't work .

```
class BookPage(QtGui.QMainWindow, UiBookInput):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.window = None
        self.threadclass = RfidThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.setupUi(self)



    def cancel_form(self):
        # self.moveToThread(self.threadclass)
        self.threadclass.stop()
        self.window = Cancel(prev=BookPage())
        QtGui.QMainWindow.close(self)
        self.window.show_form()
        self.window.show()





class RfidThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RfidThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.state = True
    def stop(self):
        self.state = False

    def run(self):
        while self.state:
            # some statment
```

Comment: Your code stucks somewhere in your while loop where it's doing the hard task, you should ensure that you set the flag to every "long" running tasks in your thread so it can `break` the loop as fast as possible. Please provide more info about whats going on inside the `while` loop

Comment: In loop I get input from RFID device. when code started I start thread and I want code do what stop thread from GUI if user want to cancel this form to open another form. and do some else.

Comment: @J4v4d. What makes you think it "doesn't work"? There's no reason why the thread in the code you've posted won't stop. Perhaps you should show a more realistic example of your actual code.